# Mongoose Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a user using Mongoose, and I want to use my own `_id`. I thought that you could convert any string to an `ObjectId` with the following code: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4fhTTRkUYNPBUSiYIhz8YHZ9wQ02')`. This is what several other Stack Overflow answers have suggested. However, when I use this code in Node, I get the following error: `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
router.post("/create_user", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  
  console.log("/create_user id : ", id); // <-- logging successfully '4fhTTRkUYNPBUSiYIhz8YHZ9wQ02'
  
  User.create({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), // <-- generating error
    name: "Joe"
  })
  .then((u) => {
    return res.json({ user: u });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("/create_user error : ", err);
    return res.json({ error: err });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that you could convert any string to an ObjectId

This is not the case, only some strings are valid ObjectIds.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I suggest you refer to the documentation.